# WXPYTHON (NameError: global name 'myFrame' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

Below is screenshot of the error. Why does it happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are trying to achieve. Although when posting to StackOverflow you should cut and paste your code into the question and not put it in a link, especially a link that is an image.
Few people will make the effort to help, if you make it difficult for them to do so.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, title="Window", pos = (100,150), size =(250,200))
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(1,'&About')
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(2,'E&xit')
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menu,'&File')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=2)
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()

    def OnAbout(self, evt):
        print("This is MyFrame")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how you even ran that code because your `if __name__ == '__main__'` and you `main` method are indented inside your `myFrame` class. Try out-indenting it I mean your end of code should be like:

```
def main():
    app = myApp()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

also, your naming convention is not pythonic.
`Python recommends UpperCamelCase for class names, CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORES for constants, and lowercase_separated_by_underscores for other names.`